# How to change windows recyclebin properties

Tags: c#, windows, shell32

---

[image]

How can I get this property of recyclebin and switch it using C#.

Comment: One of those somewhat rare no-code and short SO questions that, if not a dup, will probably be helpful to future users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way  to do so irrespective of language.

As far as I understand there is no API to configure this settings. You can *query* information about recycle bin via PInvoke ([SHQueryRecycleBin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762241(v=vs.85).aspx) and empty ([SHEmptyRecycleBin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762160(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Couple ways to touch those settings can be found in Raymond Chen's blog post - [What is default size of the Recycle Bin...](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140701-00/?p=603). Summary below:

- Official way to adjust size - via policy [Maximum allowed Recycle Bin size](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/Default.aspx?PolicyID=2667).
- Unsupported way - tweak registry settings - [Managing the Recycle bin](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/07/16/managing-the-recycle-bin-with-redirected-folders-with-vista-or-windows-7/)